# How to animate ribbon unfurling?

Tags: modeling, animation, physics, bezier-curves

I have to animate ribbon unfurling an box opening. Like below.

[image]

Got the box part down, but I'm stuck on the ribbon. What would be the best way of going around it the ribbon. Would it be best done with cloth and simulation? Or actually modelling it?

I'm really stuck, so thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm fighting the same battle. Try this. It's a bit tricky but makes a good knot. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wh62H5Njr4I